# Subreddits statistics public API

Tags: web-scraping, reddit

I would like to get statistics from [redditmetrics.com](http://redditmetrics.com/). Is there an API for that to get statistics about subreddits popularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[redditmetrics.com](http://redditmetrics.com) is not affiliated with reddit itself, so they are likely using the reddit api to poll for these metrics and save them as needed.

Unfortunately, the [reddit api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) does not currently have a feature to look at a subreddit's subscriber count at a previous date. If you wanted to use the data on [redditmetrics.com](http://redditmetrics.com), you technically could scrape the data in some way, but they have a [contact us section](http://redditmetrics.com/contact/us/), which I'm sure you could learn if they would work with you in to letting you access that data.